# Upload files with retrofit

Tags: java, android, file, upload, retrofit

I tried work with API
[My API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZTmt.png)

And Java code

```
public interface UploadAPI {
    @Multipart
    @POST("books")

    Call<AddBookResult> uploadBook(
        @Part MultipartBody.Part audios,
        @Part("image") RequestBody image,
        @Part("audio_names") List<String> audio_names,
        @Part("video_names") List<String> video_names,
        @Part("video_urls") List<String> video_urls,
        @Part("preview") RequestBody preview,
        @Part("hot") String hotParam,
        @Part("new") String newParam,
        @Part("coming") String comingParam,
        @Part("sale_offs") List<String> sale_offs,
        @Part("author") String author,
        @Part("publisher") String publisher,
        @Part("categories") List<String> categories,
        @Part("name") String name,
        @Part("price") String price
    );
}
```

Call API

[Code Java Call API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj9w1.png)

And result of respone
 Internal Server Error
:(

Comment: can you post the error?

Comment: Internal Server Error :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all internal server error (status code 500) means that you have some kind of issue with your backend or your API cannot find the path to the called endpoint controller.

Im not sure how is your backend configured, but i think it may be the path problem, try adding the "/" before **books** in request declaration like this

```
public interface UploadAPI {
    @Multipart
    @POST("/books") //here you have to put path to your controller

    Call<AddBookResult> uploadBook(
        @Part MultipartBody.Part audios,
        @Part("image") RequestBody image,
        @Part("audio_names") List<String> audio_names,
        @Part("video_names") List<String> video_names,
        @Part("video_urls") List<String> video_urls,
        @Part("preview") RequestBody preview,
        @Part("hot") String hotParam,
        @Part("new") String newParam,
        @Part("coming") String comingParam,
        @Part("sale_offs") List<String> sale_offs,
        @Part("author") String author,
        @Part("publisher") String publisher,
        @Part("categories") List<String> categories,
        @Part("name") String name,
        @Part("price") String price
    );
}
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, post the detailed log of your request, or take a look on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/f0restgump92/71b704efecbf43ac3d56fc99fb2a2853) if you want full working example  of image upload with progress bar

Comment: Tks,
I have tried and not , I think maybe I wrote the wrong API .